# String syntax - PHP unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in your code

Tags: php, string

I am using this code but getting PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF).

```
$string = "<span class=\"titlec\">" . $myname . if (strval(get_field('br_featured', $prev_id)) > 0) {echo "<span title=\"Listing\" class=\"mond\"></span>";} . "</span>"
```

Not sure what the solution would be here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You  are using an `if` within  an expression. It does not work like that.

Comment: Either move the `if` block outside the assignment statement, and there assign a string to a  variable than then you use to assign to `$string`, or use a ternary operator.

Comment: You can use the ternary operator :

    `$string = "<span class=\"titlec\">". $myname . (((string) get_field('br_featured', $prev_id) > 0) ? "<span title=\"Listing\" class=\"mond\"></span>" : "</span>");` 

Also, you can replace `strval()` with a string cast.